# Create nested OR condition using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I want to create something like:

`select * from documents where 'chapter'=3 and 'section'=4 and ('title' like '%abc% OR 'desc' like %abc%);`

How can I do this using Eloquent? I've tried using Eloquent's `whereOr` method but that doesn't seem to do anything in the generated SQL. But, even if they did, I'm not certain my current code would make them embedded like what I'm looking for.

Some of what I've got:

```
    $docSearch = DB::table('documents');

    if ($chapter > 0) {
        $docSearch->where('chapter', $chapter);
    }

    $existingManagementArray = Management::getAllManagementIDsAsArray();
    if ($management_id > 0 && in_array($management_id, $existingManagementArray)) {
        $docSearch->where('management_id', $management_id);
    } else {
        $docSearch->whereIn('management_id', $existingManagementArray);
    }

    if (strlen($term) > 0) {
        //HELP! These don't seem to change the SQL
        $docSearch->whereOr('title', 'like', "%$term%"); 
        $docSearch->whereOr('desc', 'like', "%$term%");
    }

    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $allFoundDocs = $docSearch->get();
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
DB::table('documents')->where('chapter', 3)
    ->where('section', 4)
    ->where(function($q) use($abc) {
        $q->where('title', 'like', '%'.$abc.'%')
          ->orWhere('desc', 'like', '%'.$abc.'%');
    })->get();
```

Passing a `Closure` into the `where()` method instructs the query builder to begin a constraint group.The `Closure` will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the parenthesis group.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) (section called Parameter Grouping)

Comment: This worked great. Can you describe a bit what's going on? I haven't seen the passing of a function in the Eloquent docs.

Comment: @zundi, well, you can pass closure (function) to `where()` method and add advanced constrains to parent `where()`. You can do multiple levels of nested `where()`. Don't forget to use `use()` if you want to pass some data to the closure.